# How to properly call an executable in C program runtime?

Tags: c, performance, exec, llvm, child-process

I have a C application whose one of the jobs is to call an executable file. That file has performance measurement routines inserted during compilation, at the level of intermediate code. It can measure time or L1/L2/L3 cache misses. In other words, I have modified the LLVM compiler to insert a call to that function and print the result to `stdout` for any compiled program.

Now, like I mentioned at the beginning, I would like to execute the program (with this result returned to `stdout`) from a separate C application and save that result. The way I'm doing it right now is:

```
void executeProgram(const char* filename, char* time) {
    printf("Executing selected program %s...\n", filename);
    char filePath[100] = "/home/michal/thesis/Drafts/output/";
    strcat(filePath, filename);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen(filePath, "r");
    char str[30];
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str) - 1, fp) != NULL) {
        strcat(time, str);
    }
    pclose(fp);
}
```

where `filename` is the name of the compiled executable to run. The result is saved to `time` string.

The problem is, that the results I'm getting are pretty different and unstable compared to those that are returned by simply running the executable 'by hand' from the command line (`./test16`). They look like:

```
231425 
229958 
230450 
228534 
230033 
230566 
231059 
232016 
230733 
236017 
213179 
90515 
229775 
213351 
229316 
231642 
230875
```

So they're mostly around 230000 us, with some occasional drops. The same executable, run from within the other application, produces:

```
97097 
88706 
91418 
97970 
97972 
94597 
95846 
95139 
91070 
95918 
107006 
89988 
90882 
91986 
90997 
88824 
129136 
94976 
102191 
94400 
95215 
95061 
92115 
96319 
114091 
95230 
114500 
95533 
102294 
108473 
105730
```

Note that it is the *same* executable that's being called. Yet the measured time it returns is different. The program that is being measured consists of a function call to a simple nested loop, accessing array elements. Here is the code:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

float data[1000][1000] = {0};


void test(void)
{
    int i0, i1;
    int N = 80;
    float mean[1000];
    for (i0 = 0; i0 < N; i0++)
    {
        mean[i0] = 0.0;
        for (i1 = 0; i1 < N; i1++) {
            mean[i0] += data[i0][i1];
        }
        mean[i0] /= 1000;
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting that there is something wrong in the way the program is invoked in the code, maybe the process should be forked or something? Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've confused the time units, the time is in microseconds, in fact. Okay, I will try and explain it better.

Comment: When you execute from the "other application" do you use a loop to invoke a number of times? Like `for(i=0;i<20; ++i)  executeProgram(...)`

Comment: I don't, it's ran just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt specify where exactly your time measuring subroutines are inserted, so all I can really offer is guesswork.

The results seem to hint to the exact opposite - running the application from shell is slower, so I wouldn't worry about the way you're starting the process from the C code. My guess would be - when you run your program from shell, it's the terminal that's slowing you down. When you're running the process from your C code, you pipe the output back to your 'starter' application, which is already waiting for input on the pipe.

As a side note, consider switching from `strcat` to something safer, like `strncat`.

Comment: `strcat` is a perfectly fine function if you have computed the length of the strings beforehand. However, in OPs case, he has not. `strncat` is not any safer as it leads to silent unterminated strings instead of (often crashing) overflows.

Comment: @FUZxxl When not checked for errors in the inputs, both crash the application, yes. What `strncat` is better at is preventing buffer overflow code execution type attacks (not really a case in this example, but it's really important to keep that in mind when dealing with 'foreign' strings).

Comment: If you check the lengths, then both `strcat` and `strncat` are equally safe.

Comment: But if you forget to do so, one is signifficantly more dangerous than the other. `snprintf` is still better than both.

Comment: I can't specify it in the source code, because they are not present in the source code. They are inserted during compilation, after being lowered to the LLVM-IR code. I can provide that code if you think it could help

Comment: @Kelm both unterminated strings and buffer overflows are equally dangerous. Yes, `snprintf` is even better. Or use `strlcat`.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Where are they inserted? As the very first instruction of the program, before `main()`, as a first instruction of `main()`, ...?

Comment: @FUZxxl you are correct as in they are both dangerous, they are nowhere close to be equally dangerous though. If you allow an attacker to supply a preparated string and use those functions on it, one will at worst crash the application or give false results, the other will at worst execute the attacker's code leading to compromising your system.

Comment: @Kelm Right, this is important. They are inserted right before the loop header, and right after the loop exit (inside `test` function).

Comment: @Kelm: truncation can very easily lead to information leaks.